# Existence of linearly independent set in an infinite dimensional normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Problem:** Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space and $D=\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ a countable subset of $X$. Show that there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ in $X$, satisfying $ ||y_n||<1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ , such that the set $E = \{x_n + \frac{1}{n} y_n :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent.

I am having trouble defining a sequence of that form, with linearly independent terms. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Let $F_n = \operatorname{span} \: \{ x_k + \frac{1}{k}y_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}$. So you start with $F_0 = \{0\}$. What constraints are then imposed on the choice of $y_{n+1}$?

Comment: Use a recursive construction, I would say.

Comment: $y_{n+1}$ must be such that $x_{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} y_{n+1} \notin \operatorname{span} \: \{x_{n} + \frac{1}{n} y_{n}\}$, which means that $y_{n+1}$ must not be in $ \operatorname{span} \: \( \{x_n\}, \{x_{n+1}\}, \{y_n\} \)$ ?